# mvn test fails but running the test from IntelliJ IDEA pass

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, junit

I have this a test that I run under

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest

@Test
    public void testFind() throws IOException {


Review<Hostel> hostelByComplaintId =
                hostelService.findByComplaintId(complaintId).orElse(null);

        assertThat(hostelByComplaintId).isNotNull();
}
```

when I run the test from the command line `mvn test` I got this error

```
Failed tests:
Expecting actual not to be null
```

but when I run it from IntelliJ IDEA, the test does not fail

Comment: How can I reproduce your issue? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Not enough information. As a blind guess: do you use same maven version in terminal and intellij?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just write complete command if there any test cases in your project found it will run

```
mvn clean install
```

if you want to disable run test cases

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```